# My input is "qwerty \n asdf " nextLine() takes input as "qwerty \n asdf "

Tags: java

Shouldn't the input read by nextLine() be "qwerty " as nextLine() should read my input only till it encounters \n.
This is my first question, Sorry if there's something wrong.
Help really appreciated.
Thank you.
My code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Kush 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
}

}
```

input :
abcd \n qwerty

output :
abcd \n qwerty

Comment: if you input `\n` it´s most likely not a line separator but just two chars as `\n`

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Can i enter a line separator manually

Comment: @KushagrTyagi This won't work. To take in the input (by `sc.nextLine()`) you will have to open the console window. Just add a `System.out.println("Enter:");` before `System.out.println(sc.nextLine())`

Comment: @KushagrTyagi As for the line separators, the system reads it as `\\n`, which is stored as `\n`, and not as a line feed.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder I know that but what i wanted to ask was that if i had a line separator in my input, shouldn't the nextLine() method stop taking more input. In my case the output should have been "abcd "

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder Did not know that the system adds a backslash while reading \n. Thanks

Comment: Yes well that is the point of `Scanner.nextLine()`, but you don't have a line feed in your string, do you? :)

Comment: @KushagrTyagi Only if you type it in.

Comment: if you press enter it should add a real `\n` I guess!?

Comment: @xander So lesson learned \n is not a line feed in java, If i type it in ?

Comment: @KushagrTyagi To *grossly oversimplify*, an enter from the keyboard is `\n`. But when you type in `\n`, it becomes '\\' for '\', and `n` for `n`. The system reads '\' and the char after that as an escape sequence.

Comment: If you want to be sure just print all the chars `sc.nextLine()` returns and see what you actually get (with a loop and `String,charAt` for example)!

Answer (score 1):

The `\n` in input you are providing is treated as two characters `\` & `n`
instead of a single newline char `'\n'`. To input a new line you should press enter key.

Below code will give you a better explanation.

```
String s = "abcd \n defg"; // here '\n' is a newline char
Scanner in = new Scanner(s);
while(in.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(in.next());
}
```

Output:

```
abcd
defg
```